# Operations on transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDu0Z.png)

I don't understand how I'm supposed to approach this question. My initial idea was  to do matrix multiplication based on S and T. However, It says that (SoT)(x) is a 2x2 matrix, but T = 3x2 and S = 2x3 so the product of T*S would be a 3x3 matrix.

Edit: I realized that doing S*T would yield a 2x2 matrix, but I'm still not sure if this is the correct method.

Comment: Depends on the order of the product. In one direction, its $3\times3$, and in the other, it's $2\times2$.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. Does SoT mean S*T? Which would yield a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: I think the only meaningful interpretation is $S\circ T=S\cdot T$.